# How to calculate and place circles on an rect area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, canvas, jcanvas

I'm trying to draw some charts on a Canvas Area. My Problem is following...

I have 1-4 (or more) circles to draw. The canvas size is like 500 x 400 px. How can i now calculate the max Radius of each circle to place all on this canvas and get the position (center x/y) of each circle? So each circle could be optimal placed on the area with some margin to each other?

here some example screens to show you what i mean...

[image: placing four circles]
[image: Place the circles like a table]

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the maximum radius you can use

```
    var numberOfSections = 4;
    var width = 500;
    var height = 400;
    var R = Math.sqrt((width * height) / numberOfSections) / 2

    var MX = Math.round(width / (R * 2)); // max amount of squares that can fit on the width
    var MY = Math.round(height / (R * 2)); // max amount of squares that can fit on the height

var skipLast = 0;
var numOfCalculatedCircles = MX*MY;
if(numOfCalculatedCircles != numberOfSections) {

    if(numOfCalculatedCircles < numberOfSections) {
        console.log('numOfCalculatedCircles',numOfCalculatedCircles);
        MX = MX + Math.ceil((numberOfSections - numOfCalculatedCircles)/MY);
        if(MX*MY != numberOfSections) {
            skipLast = Math.abs(MX*MY - numberOfSections);
        }
    } else {
        skipLast = numOfCalculatedCircles - numberOfSections;;
    }

    console.log('MX*MY',MX*MY);
}
// recalculate the radius for X
if (R * 2 * MX > width) {
    R = (width/2) / MX;
}

// recalculate the radius for Y
if (R * 2 * MY > height) {
    R = (height/2) / MY
}
```

Calculate the margins for X and Y:

```
    var circlesWidth = R * 2 * MX;
    var circlesHeight = R * 2 * MY;

    var marginX = 0;
    var marginY = 0;
    if (circlesWidth < width) {
        marginX = (width - circlesWidth) / 2
    }
    if (circlesHeight < height) {
        marginY = (height - circlesHeight) / 2
    }
```

After that you can calculate the centers:

```
var RY = marginY + R;
var radiusPadding = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < MY; i++) {
    var RX = marginX + R;
    for (var j = 0; j < MX; j++) {
        if(i === MY - 1) {
          if(j === MX - skipLast) {
            break;
          }
        }
        canvas.drawArc({
            fromCenter: true,
            strokeStyle: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            start: 0,
            end: 360,
            radius: R - radiusPadding,
            x: RX,
            y: RY
        });

        RX += 2 * R;
    }

    RY += 2 * R;
}
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: It is still incomplete but it may work in this particular example: http://jsfiddle.net/dhM96/4/

Comment: looks interesting but i don't know how to modify it. i've tried following but it draws 6 circles with a to big radius and wrong positions.

var numberOfSections = data.length, // currently: 4
   R                = Math.sqrt((cWidth * cHeight) / numberOfSections) / 2,
   centers          = [];
  
  for( var x = R, y = R; ; x += 2 * R ) {
   if(x >= cWidth) {
    x  = R;
    y += R;
    if( y >= cHeight ) break;
     }  
   canvas.drawArc({
    fromCenter: true,
    strokeStyle: strokeStyle,
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
    start: 0,
    end: 360,
    radius: R,
    x: x,
    y: y
   });
  }

Comment: @HR123 sorry this answer is incomplete and it's more complex to answer you question than i thought. I've created a jsfiddle that you can use as a reference: http://jsfiddle.net/hn7u7/3/. If this works for you, I will update my answer.

Comment: thank you very much!!!
it's very difficult... you've done great work.
but there's a small problem... if you change the numberOfSections to 2 or 5 or something like it doesn't work anymore...

i've tried to round the numbers but your code/math is to difficult for me... hope you can help me another time with this last step.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving enough of your placement constraints.

Anyway, assuming a free space of `F` pixels along the rectangle edges and `f` between the circles, the maximum radius on `X` is `Rx = (Width - 2 F - (Nx-1) f) / 2` and on `Y`, `R y = (Height - 2F - (Ny-1) f) / 2`. (`Nx` circles horizontally, `Ny` vertically.) Take the smallest of the two.

The centers will be at `(F + (2 Rx + f) Ix + Rx, F + (2 Ry + f) Iy + Ry)`, `0 <= Ix < Nx`, `0 <= Iy < Ny`.

Answer (score -1):

The [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) you are asking about is hard to solve. Best approach in your case is to use a given table such as **http://www.packomania.com**. If you can, restrict yourself to a square.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. thats to complex i think. maybe the new image above is more helpful. i want to place them like a table.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the knapstack. It's a packing problem ! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem. And the instance of the problem queried by the OP is plain trivial.

Comment: I answered the original question. Only after editing it got that trivial.